# Почему команда pip list из активного виртуального окружения выводит список глобальных зависимостей (пакетов) вместо зависимостей окружения?

Tags: python, virtualenv, зависимости

Создал проект. Создал виртуально окружение. Активировал его. Установил нужные библиотеки (pip install ...). Проект работает - все в порядке. В активированном виртуальном окружении пишу pip list и мне выдает список глобальных зависимостей вместо зависимостей окружения. ???  Виртуально окружение активировано!!! В консоле выводит следующее:

```
Package                 Version
----------------------- ---------
altgraph                0.16.1
appdirs                 1.4.4
astroid                 2.3.1
async-lru               1.0.2
beautifulsoup4          4.7.1
bottle                  0.12.18
bs4                     0.0.1
buildozer               1.2.0
certifi                 2019.3.9
cfgv                    3.1.0
chardet                 3.0.4
Click                   7.0
colorama                0.4.1
cycler                  0.10.0
Cython                  0.29.19
defusedxml              0.6.0
distlib                 0.3.1
Django                  2.2.5
django-allauth          0.41.0
django-bootstrap4       1.1.1
django-ckeditor         5.9.0
django-js-asset         1.2.2
django-modeltranslation 0.14.4
django-recaptcha3       0.1.0
docutils                0.16
filelock                3.0.12
future                  0.17.1
fuzzywuzzy              0.17.0
gTTS                    2.0.3
gTTS-token              1.1.3
identify                1.4.23
idna                    2.8
importlib-metadata      1.7.0
isort                   4.3.21
Kivy                    1.11.1
kivy-deps.glew          0.2.0
kivy-deps.gstreamer     0.2.0
kivy-deps.sdl2          0.2.0
Kivy-examples           1.11.1
Kivy-Garden             0.1.4
kiwisolver              1.1.0
langdetect              1.0.8
lazy-object-proxy       1.4.2
lxml                    4.5.2
macholib                1.11
matplotlib              3.1.2
mccabe                  0.6.1
mock                    4.0.2
MouseInfo               0.1.3
mss                     5.1.0
nodeenv                 1.4.0
numpy                   1.17.4
oauthlib                3.1.0
opencv-python           4.2.0.32
packaging               20.4
pefile                  2019.4.18
pexpect                 4.8.0
Pillow                  7.0.0
pip                     20.0.2
pluggy                  0.13.1
pre-commit              2.6.0
ptyprocess              0.6.0
py                      1.9.0
pyaes                   1.6.1
pyasn1                  0.4.6
PyAudio                 0.2.11
PyAutoGUI               0.9.50
pycryptodome            3.8.2
PyGetWindow             0.0.8
Pygments                2.6.1
PyInstaller             3.4
pylint                  2.4.2
PyMsgBox                1.0.8
pyparsing               2.4.5
pyperclip               1.8.0
pypiwin32               223
PyQt5                   5.15.0
PyQt5-sip               12.8.0
PyRect                  0.1.4
Pyrogram                1.0.7
PyScreeze               0.1.26
PySocks                 1.7.1
pyTelegramBotAPI        3.6.7
pytesseract             0.3.4
python-dateutil         2.8.1
python-docx             0.8.10
python3-openid          3.1.0
pyttsx3                 2.71
PyTweening              1.0.3
pytz                    2019.2
pywin32                 224
pywin32-ctypes          0.2.0
PyYAML                  5.3.1
re101                   0.4.0
requests                2.22.0
requests-oauthlib       1.3.0
rsa                     4.0
selenium                3.141.0
setuptools              40.8.0
sh                      1.13.1
six                     1.15.0
sockets                 1.0.0
soupsieve               1.9.1
SpeechRecognition       3.8.1
sqlparse                0.3.0
toml                    0.10.1
tox                     3.17.1
translate               3.5.0
transliterate           1.10.2
typed-ast               1.4.0
urllib3                 1.25.3
virtualenv              20.0.25
vk                      2.0.2
WMI                     1.5.1
wrapt                   1.11.2
zipp                    3.1.0
```

Comment: скопируйте в текст вопроса пример вывода консоли при вызове `pip list`

Comment: Вот сделал как и просили)

Comment: А если `python -m pip list`?

Comment: Тоже самое - ничего не меняется

Comment: Вы уверены, что это модули системного интерпретатора? Может, установленные в виртуальном окружении библиотеки так много зависимостей подтянули?